# How do I ask a question that applies to the default flavor of Ubuntu specifically?

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions

If I would like ask a question that applies to just the default flavor of Ubuntu specifically (not Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu GNOME, etc.), how should I phrase and tag it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's specific to standard Ubuntu's DE (Desktop Environment) *Unity*, use the tag [unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/unity). Other flavours use other DEs (Xubuntu=XFCE; Lubuntu=LXDE; Kubuntu=KDE;...)

Additionally, you can clearly write in your question, that you want answers about standard Ubuntu with Unity and nothing that is different in other flavours. So simple is it. :)